# Maven: how to export project with sources and dependencies

Tags: maven-2, maven-dependency-plugin

I have Maven project with dependencies in repo and stuff. I want to "export" its sources with all dependencies so that I can successfully open it in IDE without Maven running on a machine.

When packaging project into war file, it has all dependencies packed with it.

So I want to have all that dependencies plus my sources gathered in one place, which can be opened with IDE (Eclipse or IDEA) all those libraries detected?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try maven-dependency-plugin with goal [copy-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html)

```
<project>
[...]
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
          <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
          <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
          <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
[...]
</project>
```

**PS.**
Are you aware of maven and IDE integration (for [Eclipse](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html) p.e.)? Maven can generate project for particular IDE and include all dependent jars as variables (pointing to these jars in local repository), so there is no need to use copy dependecies to subfolder.

Comment: >>Are you aware of maven and IDE integration

If you are talking about opening POM file in IDE which will then discover sources and dependencies, that's not what I want. I just need to copy the project sources and libs and be able to open and run it on the machine without maven installed. So I think, I'll use the plugin you're talking about

Comment: I have a problem with this plugin. If I have a <scope>compile</scope> in my dependency - it compiles, but isn't copied by dependency plugin. But if I change a scope to "runtime" or "import" it's popping up a "compile error":
" Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project AnnotationsProcessors: Compilation failure... ...annotations/processors/ComplexityProcessor.java:[20,28] cannot find symbol". I have this dependency installed in local maven repository and it builds fine.

Answer (score 10):

Actually, there is nothing that will create a bundle with sources **and** dependencies out of the box. For this, you'll need to use a combination of the some plugins.

For dependencies, the [Maven 2 Dependency Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/dependency-maven-plugin/introduction.html) and its [`copy-dependencies`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html) will help as pointed out by cetnar.

For sources, you might need the [Maven Source Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/) and its [`source:aggregate`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/aggregate-mojo.html) goal (or maybe the [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) and the pre-defined `src` descriptor but `source:aggregate` is handy for multi-modules builds).

To bind the whole thing together (and maybe unpack sources), I'd use the [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

Comment: I suppouse by mean `my sources gathered in one place` glaz666 mean regural java project with sources (from VCS or not) and all dependencies in lib subfolder. +1 for source:aggregate for multimodule.

Answer (score 0):

War with sources

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <directory>${build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
          <targetPath>src</targetPath>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```