# NoSuchAlgorithmException with Bouncy Castle when not in Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, bouncycastle

We use bouncy castle for encryption.
We do not have any problem when we laucn our code in debug mode in Eclipse but when we manually launch the JAR we have a `NoSuchAlgorithmException`.
The JAR is built using the maven plugin configuration

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is our code :

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/OAEPWithSHA256AndMGF1Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
return cipher.doFinal(data);
```

We have changed the security policy to the unlimited one given by Oracle but the problem still remains.
Any ideas?

Comment: A solution is to add Bouncy Castle provider to the JRE java.security provider, the Bouncy Castle JAR in the JRE external libraries and exclude it from the JAR.
But it is a pain when dealing with multiple deployments.
Is there an other solution ?

Comment: The answer is in an other post, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329068/bouncycastle-error-jce-cannot-authenticate-the-provider-bc-with-jar-with-depe

Comment: using spring boot plugin instead of shade plugin solved the problem